# How to get a Bitmap from a View including shadow

Tags: android, android-layout, view, bitmap, android-view

I have a complex Layout with some Views inside it. Some of this Views has an elevation (so they have a shadow).

Now I want to create a bitmap (a screenshot) of the entire Layout (and childs, of course) including the shadow, and save the image on a file.

I already tried the following two solutions and I'm able to save the image of the Layout in the file. The only problem is that the shadow is not included in the image.

**Test 1**

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
buildDrawingCache(true);
setChildrenDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(getDrawingCache());
setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

**Test 2**

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth, viewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.draw(c);
```

How can I include tha shadow in the Bitmap?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek I ended up to use [this library](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-materialshadowninepatch) and its `MaterialShadowContainerView`. Now the shadow is included in the Bitmap.